# My awk script not using all lines of input

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

FYI: $NEWFILE is newfile.vcf

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[\t]+"}; NR <= 2 || $6 >= 100 {print $0 > "newfile.vcf"}'
$NEWFILE
```

So this is my awk code.  I have a list of data, and column 6 must be greater than or equal to 100.  I also want to ignore the first 2 lines.
The data is delimited by tabs, but is ended with a new line.  My code only does one line of the data, which happens to have column 6 be greater than 100. (It does, however, ignore the first 2 lines), then stops.  The rest of the lines do not show up in newfile.vcf  I'm guessing because of the new line.  Anyway how can I fix this?

INPUT:

```
                                                     NAME1    NAME2    NAME3
#CHROM   POS    ID    ALT    REF   QUAL   FILTER    953_102   953_103    953_104
Chr1    1058     .     TAA    TAAA    999   StandBias
Chr1    1071     .     TAA    TAAA    118   StandBias
Chr1    1084     .     TAA    TAAA    27.5  StandBias
Chr1    1089     .     TAA    TAAA    999   StandBias
```

Desired Ouput:

```
                                                     NAME1    NAME2    NAME3
#CHROM   POS    ID    ALT    REF   QUAL   FILTER    953_102   953_103    953_104
Chr1    1058     .     TAA    TAAA    999   StandBias
Chr1    1071     .     TAA    TAAA    118   StandBias
Chr1    1089     .     TAA    TAAA    999   StandBias
```

Current Ouput:

```
                                                     NAME1    NAME2    NAME3
#CHROM   POS    ID    ALT    REF   QUAL   FILTER    953_102   953_103    953_104
Chr1    1058     .     TAA    TAAA    999   StandBias
```

Program (Although the stuff until the awk is kind of irrelevant to the question.  Everything before the awk works as intended.)

```
#! /bin/bash
#removing the extra stuff at the top of datafile.
NEWFILE=newfile.vcf
LINESINLEGEND=`wc legend.txt | awk {'print $1'}`
LINESINLEGEND=$((LINESINLEGEND-1))
NEWLEGEND=`tail -n$LINESINLEGEND $2`

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "usage: filename.vcf <optional>legend.txt"
fi

if [ $# -eq 2 ]
then
    printf "$NEWLEGEND" > temp
    CUTME=`cut -f 5 temp | cut -d " " -f 4 temp | tr -s '\n' '\t'`
    rm temp
    printf "" > $NEWFILE
    printf "\t" >> $NEWFILE
    printf "\t" >> $NEWFILE
    printf "\t" >> $NEWFILE
    printf "\t" >> $NEWFILE
    printf "\t" >> $NEWFILE
    printf "\t" >> $NEWFILE
    printf "\t" >> $NEWFILE
    printf "\t" >> $NEWFILE
    printf "\t" >> $NEWFILE
    printf "$CUTME\n" >> $NEWFILE

    grep -v "^\#\#" $1 >> $NEWFILE
    awk 'NR==1 || $6 >= 100' newfile.vcf > newfile.vcf
    #suggested code makes nothing appear in newfile.vcf
fi
```

Comment: I wonder how that command even works! Please post some sample lines from your input and your expected output.

Comment: Added input and output

Comment: using awk 'NR==1 || $6 >= 100' newfile.vcf > newfile.vcf prints nothing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command should do it:

```
awk 'NR==1 || $6 >= 100' input.file > newfile.vcf
```

`NR==1` matches the first line of input. `$6 >= 100` matches those lines where `QUAL` is greater or equal than `100`. The default action in awk is to print the whole while of input to output. That's why you can omit the `{print $0}`.

You don't need to specify `TAB` as the delimiter since it is one of the default delimiters.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, however my program hangs after using that command.

Comment: Your code worked, I just created a temp and used it as input.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
 awk -F"\t" '{if ( $6 > 100 || NR<=2) print $0}' input.vcf > newfile.vcf
```

Of course, with awk there are more than a few ways to skin the cat. Other than the $6 token being written as 6$, your script really should have worked. If this script I just wrote does the same thing, then perhaps not all of your lines on your input file are tab delimited.

Comment: Sorry I rewrote the command by hand, it was $6 on my machine.  I tried your code, and my newfile.vcf is blank. But maybe you're right about not all the lines being tab delimited, it's hard to tell there is so much data.

Comment: On the Command line try `awk -F"\t" '$6!="" || NR<=3' yourinput.file | wc -l` That will count how many records are returned by awk that don't have a NULL $6 token or are in the first two records (suggesting the line is not tab delimited). Compare that to `wc -l yourinputfile.txt` If the two don't match, then you have a problem.

Comment: You won't need to pass `-F"\t"`. It is a delimiter by default

Comment: @anton5999 You are telling `your program hangs`. Please show your program.

Comment: Hi JNevill, The two commands are different.  The first one yields 85 while the 2nd one yields 147.  Also hek2gml I will post the program right now, just need to explain what it does.

Comment: but @hek2mgl, I meant your code causes my program to hang.  Even if I just put your code in the terminal it would hang.